# How to assign a variable/integer to a image?

Tags: c#

I'm super new to c# and i have got a problem i have been trying to figure out for the past couple of days anyways i am trying to make a blackjack game but i cant figure out for the life of me how to associate the images of the random cards that show up in the picture box's to a variable/integer so i can make a function to add the values of the cards, if y'all could give me some ideas that would be great!

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;



namespace pokerapp
{

    public partial class pokergame : Form
    {

        //Card Varibles
        int card1 = 10;
        int card2 = 10;
        int card3 = 10;
        int card4 = 10;
        int card5 = 10;
        int card6 = 10;
        int card7 = 10;
        int card8 = 10;
        int card9 = 10;
        int card10 = 10;
        int card11 = 10;
        int card12 = 10;
        int card13 = 10;
        int card14 = 10;
        int card15 = 10;
        int card16 = 10;
        int card17 = 10;
        int card18 = 10;
        int card19 = 10;
        int card20 = 10;
        int card21 = 9;
        int card22 = 9;
        int card23 = 9;
        int card24 = 9;
        int card25 = 8;
        int card26 = 8;
        int card27 = 8;
        int card28 = 8;
        int card29 = 7;
        int card30 = 7;
        int card31 = 7;
        int card32 = 7;
        int card33 = 6;
        int card34 = 6;
        int card35 = 6;
        int card36 = 6;
        int card37 = 5;
        int card38 = 5;
        int card39 = 5;
        int card40 = 5;
        int card41 = 4;
        int card42 = 4;
        int card43 = 4;
        int card44 = 4;
        int card45 = 3;
        int card46 = 3;
        int card47 = 3;
        int card48 = 3;
        int card49 = 2;
        int card50 = 2;
        int card51 = 2;
        int card52 = 2;










        public pokergame()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        Random random = new Random();

        List<Image> images = new List<Image>();

        public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            pictureBox1.Image = images[random.Next(0, images.Count - 1)];
            pictureBox2.Image = images[random.Next(0, images.Count - 1)];
            pictureBox14.Image = images[random.Next(0, images.Count - 1)];
            pictureBox13.Image = images[random.Next(0, images.Count - 1)];

            button2.Enabled = true;
            button1.Enabled = false;
        }



        public void pokergame_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pictureBox3.Visible = false;
            pictureBox4.Visible = false;
            pictureBox5.Visible = false;
            pictureBox6.Visible = false;
            pictureBox7.Visible = false;
            pictureBox8.Visible = false;
            pictureBox9.Visible = false;
            pictureBox10.Visible = false;
            pictureBox11.Visible = false;
            pictureBox12.Visible = false;
            //label1.Text = Form1.textBox1.text;
            button1.Enabled = true;
            button2.Enabled = false;


            images.Add(pokerapp.Properties.Resources._1);
            images.Add(pokerapp.Properties.Resources._2);
            images.Add(pokerapp.Properties.Resources._3);
            images.Add(pokerapp.Properties.Resources._4);
            images.Add(pokerapp.Properties.Resources._5);
            images.Add(pokerapp.Properties.Resources._6);
            images.Add(pokerapp.Properties.Resources._7);
            images.Add(pokerapp.Properties.Resources._8);
            images.Add(pokerapp.Properties.Resources._9);
            images.Add(pokerapp.Properties.Resources._10);
            images.Add(pokerapp.Properties.Resources._11);
            images.Add(pokerapp.Properties.Resources._12);
            images.Add(pokerapp.Properties.Resources._13);
            images.Add(pokerapp.Properties.Resources._14);
            images.Add(pokerapp.Properties.Resources._15);
            images.Add(pokerapp.Properties.Resources._16);
            images.Add(pokerapp.Properties.Resources._17);
            images.Add(pokerapp.Properties.Resources._18);
            images.Add(pokerapp.Properties.Resources._19);
            images.Add(pokerapp.Properties.Resources._20);
            images.Add(pokerapp.Properties.Resources._21);
            images.Add(pokerapp.Properties.Resources._22);
            images.Add(pokerapp.Properties.Resources._23);
            images.Add(pokerapp.Properties.Resources._24);
            images.Add(pokerapp.Properties.Resources._25);
            images.Add(pokerapp.Properties.Resources._26);
            images.Add(pokerapp.Properties.Resources._27);
            images.Add(pokerapp.Properties.Resources._28);
            images.Add(pokerapp.Properties.Resources._29);
            images.Add(pokerapp.Properties.Resources._30);
            images.Add(pokerapp.Properties.Resources._31);
            images.Add(pokerapp.Properties.Resources._32);
            images.Add(pokerapp.Properties.Resources._33);
            images.Add(pokerapp.Properties.Resources._34);
            images.Add(pokerapp.Properties.Resources._35);
            images.Add(pokerapp.Properties.Resources._36);
            images.Add(pokerapp.Properties.Resources._37);
            images.Add(pokerapp.Properties.Resources._38);
            images.Add(pokerapp.Properties.Resources._39);
            images.Add(pokerapp.Properties.Resources._40);
            images.Add(pokerapp.Properties.Resources._41);
            images.Add(pokerapp.Properties.Resources._42);
            images.Add(pokerapp.Properties.Resources._43);
            images.Add(pokerapp.Properties.Resources._44);
            images.Add(pokerapp.Properties.Resources._45);
            images.Add(pokerapp.Properties.Resources._46);
            images.Add(pokerapp.Properties.Resources._47);
            images.Add(pokerapp.Properties.Resources._48);
            images.Add(pokerapp.Properties.Resources._49);
            images.Add(pokerapp.Properties.Resources._50);
            images.Add(pokerapp.Properties.Resources._51);
            images.Add(pokerapp.Properties.Resources._52);
        }



        int hitButtonClickCount = 0;

        public void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Random random = new Random();

            if (hitButtonClickCount == 0)
            {
                    pictureBox3.Visible = true;
                    pictureBox3.Image = images[random.Next(0, images.Count - 1)];
                    //pictureBox3.Location = new Point(86, 130);
                    hitButtonClickCount++;

            }
            else if (hitButtonClickCount == 1)
            {
                    pictureBox4.Visible = true;
                    pictureBox4.Image = images[random.Next(0, images.Count - 1)];
                    //pictureBox4.Location = new Point(100, 140);
                    hitButtonClickCount++;


            }
            else if (hitButtonClickCount == 2)
            {
                    pictureBox5.Visible = true;
                    pictureBox5.Image = images[random.Next(0, images.Count - 1)];
                   // pictureBox5.Location = new Point(241, 197);
                    hitButtonClickCount++;


            }
            else if (hitButtonClickCount == 3)
            {
                    pictureBox6.Visible = true;
                    pictureBox6.Image = images[random.Next(0, images.Count - 1)];
                   // pictureBox5.Location = new Point(241, 197);
                    hitButtonClickCount++;


            }
            else if (hitButtonClickCount == 4)
            {
                pictureBox7.Visible = true;
                pictureBox7.Image = images[random.Next(0, images.Count - 1)];
                // pictureBox5.Location = new Point(241, 197);
                hitButtonClickCount++;
                button2.Enabled = false;

            }

        }



        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pictureBox1.Image = null;
            pictureBox2.Image = null;
            pictureBox3.Image = null;
            pictureBox4.Image = null;
            pictureBox5.Image = null;
            pictureBox6.Image = null;
            pictureBox7.Image = null;
            pictureBox8.Image = null;
            pictureBox9.Image = null;
            pictureBox10.Image = null;
            pictureBox11.Image = null;
            pictureBox12.Image = null;
            pictureBox13.Image = null;
            pictureBox14.Image = null;
            pictureBox3.Visible = false;
            pictureBox4.Visible = false;
            pictureBox5.Visible = false;
            pictureBox6.Visible = false;
            pictureBox7.Visible = false;
            pictureBox8.Visible = false;
            pictureBox9.Visible = false;
            pictureBox10.Visible = false;
            pictureBox11.Visible = false;
            pictureBox12.Visible = false;

            button1.Enabled = true;
            button2.Enabled = false;
            hitButtonClickCount = 0;
        }


        public void Points()
        {

            if (pictureBox1.Image == images[0])
            {
                label3.Text = "1/10";


            }

        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            button2.Enabled = false;
            button4.Enabled = false;
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: Sorry but I am unclear of your question.. what do you mean by assign a variable integer to image? Also, your code is a bit too long, there's no need to copy the whole program, where are you stuck??

Comment: i really don't know how to ask the question any other way :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, try and do some reading up on arrays and Lists. This will help shorten your code and make it easier for you to read.

With your question.
Try putting the cards in an array. and then pick a random number instead of a random image. Use this random number to select the correct corresponding card image and card value. You will only need to ensure that they are correctly lined up with each other.

You can access the addresses of a list the same way you would an array.
List.Items[random_int]

Comment: is this kind of what you meant?? or is there a better way because it seems like its going to have to be awfully long because i would have to use 52 "else if" statements for every card??      images = new int[52];

            int r = random.Next(images.Count());


            if (r == images[0])
            {

                pictureBox1.Image = pokerapp.Properties.Resources._1;


            }
            else if(r == images[1])
            {

                pictureBox1.Image = pokerapp.Properties.Resources._2;

            }